# Workaround expo react native web splashscreen

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-web

Is there any existing workaround to show a splashscreen on web? It is not yet supported, and I'd like to avoid seeing a white screen while loading the website.

[image]

Ref.: https://docs.expo.io/versions/v41.0.0/sdk/splash-screen/

Known issue on github: https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/10839

Comment: Any solution???

Comment: Nope.. I didnt get any solution yet

Answer (score 2):

I tested (and use) it with SDK 47 and adapted the example on https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/splash-screen/#usage like this (I simplified some components and functions here for better readability, so this example never "run" like this in reality):

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Text, View, Platform } from 'react-native';
import Entypo from '@expo/vector-icons/Entypo';
import * as SplashScreen from 'expo-splash-screen';
import * as Font from 'expo-font';
import { runAllTheInitStuff } from './init';
import SomeProvider from './SomeProvider';
import AnotherProvider from './AnotherProvider';
import WebSplashScreen from './WebSplashScreen';

// Keep the splash screen visible while we fetch resources
SplashScreen.preventAutoHideAsync();

export default function App() {
  const [appIsReady, setAppIsReady] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function prepare() {
      await runAllTheInitStuff();
      // Tell the application to render
      setAppIsReady(true);
      // hide splash screen
      await SplashScreen.hideAsync();
    }

    prepare();
  }, []);

  // check if app is ready
  if(!appIsReady) {
    // check if we are in web
    if(Platform.OS === 'web') {
      return <WebSplashScreen />;
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }

  return (
    <SomeProvider>
      <AnotherProvider>
        <View
          style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
          <Text>SplashScreen Demo! </Text>
          <Entypo name="rocket" size={30} />
        </View>
      </AnotherProvider>
    </SomeProvider>
  );
}
```

I do not use a `<View>` component as first entry point, but a lot of provider, so it would be quite challenging to use `onLayout` prop in my case. That's the reason why hiding the splash screen is done directly in the `useEffect` hook...

The `WebSplashScreen` component can be anything (i.e. the splash screen used in mobile app as image or what ever), I use a simple activity indicator from a material ui library...